# Request for errata for Automorphic Forms on GL(2)

Tags: langlands-conjectures, automorphic-forms

Edit (7/21/2014): We have finished proofreading Jacquet-Langlands and posted it to Robert Langlands's publications site. If you would like a copy, please download it from here:

http://publications.ias.edu/rpl/paper/60

Many thanks to everyone who submitted comments. If you see any more errors, please let us know. My email address is my first initial and then my last name, without spaces or other characters in between, and then ias.edu.

End Edit---------

Hello everyone,

I'm currently proofreading Hervé Jacquet's and Robert Langlands's *Automorphic Forms on GL(2)* for future republication. I was wondering if some of you had noticed mistakes in it that we might correct.

Mathematical errors, misspellings, typos---any mistake, no matter how small, is welcome!

Comment: Are you talking about the book by Jacquet and Langlands, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I've just corrected the question text. Thank you, wccanard!

Comment: My question may seem  obvious, but did you ask Jacquet?
One year he was teaching a course at Columbia on this book, and kept telling us half-jokingly how many errors he found in it. 

Comment: Hi Joël, not yet, but I will. Thanks! What is your full name, if you don't mind my asking? If it's OK, when I write to him I would like to mention that I learned of his comments from a former student of his.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on his user name?

Comment: @stankewicz while this works 'now (when you wrote your comment) I am not sure it worked at the time the original comment was written.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 6.1 (ii) on page 111: .... if and only if $n \geq |p-q|$

I am not so sure about the following, which might stem from an unconventional notation only, which I might have overlooked:

page 271 (vi) .. $\pi i$ instead of $\pi$ in the function field formula

page 272 (vii): ... but $\frac{\log q}{4 \pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi i/\log q} \dots$

similar for (viii)

Comment: My apologies for being so late! I think I see what you are referring to, but I wonder about which edition of GL(2) you are using? I looked on the site publications.ias.edu/rpl and in a copy of the printed Springer notes from 1970, but neither matches the page numbers you've given...

Comment: In the first comment, related to Lemma 6.1(ii), do you mean that $n \geq a + b$ should be changed to $n \geq |p - q|$?