# A typo in Jacquet-Langlands

Tags: automorphic-forms

On pages 516-517 of "Automorphic forms on $GL(2)$", there is a list of expressions contributing to Selberg trace formula.

In (IV), should there be an additional $\frac{1}{2}$ multiple?

In (VII), the function field case, should the upper limit of the integral be $\frac{4 \pi i}{\mathrm{log}\:q}$ (instead of $\frac{2 \pi}{\mathrm{log}\:q}$) and the multiple preceding the integral should be $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ (instead of $\frac{\mathrm{log}\:q}{4\pi}$)?

Is (VII), the number field case correct as written there? Are all the other cases correct? Is there a complete list of mistakes in this book somewhere?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/135110/3803

Comment: @PeterHumphries thanks, did not notice that, my bad. I looked up the pdf file, it appears that either my suggestions are wrong, or they are wrong. So it does not completely resolve the question.

Comment: Have you tried comparing with other presentations of the Selberg trace formula?  E.g., Gelbart's book or lecture notes, or Arthur's expositions?